# передача из формы в БД php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, form

Возникла некая проблема при создание формы. То есть, при заполнении таблицы нужно создать в БД таблицу с названием, которое содержит переменная из таблицы. Проверку на существующую таблицу проходит успешно, но далше не заходит. Не могу понять в чем проблема.
КОД ОБРАБОТЧИКА

```
if (isset($_POST['oa-submit'])) {
include_once 'dbh_oa.php';

$cl_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$nick = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nick']); //переменная-имя таблицы
$position = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['position']);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['category']);
$gang = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gang']);

if (empty($cl_name) || empty($nick) || empty($gang) || empty($position) || empty($category)) { //проверка на заполненность
    header('Location: ../view/adduser.php?signup_oa=empty'); //редирект при ошибке
    exit();
}else{
    $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW TABLES FROM ".$dBName); //сделано для поиска
    $quntity = mysqli_num_rows($sqli);

    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)) {//передача массива таблиц

        for ($i=0; $i < $quntity ; $i++) { 
            if ($rows[$i] == $nick) {  //если таблица с таким именем уже существует - редирект
                header('Location: ../view/adduser.php?signup_oa=exists');
                exit();
            }
        }
        //до сих пор работает, а дальше - запрос на создание таблицы. ошибку не выдает, но и таблицу создать не может. просто перекидывает на файл обработчика и тупик.
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$nick." (clerk_id INT(3) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, clerk_category INT(3) NOT NULL, clerk_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, clerk_position VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, clerk_gang VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, clerk_notes TEXT(10000) NULL);";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($result) {
            $sql_oa = "INSERT INTO ".$nick." (clerk_category, clerk_name, clerk_position, clerk_gang, clerk_notes) VALUES ('$category', '$cl_name', '$position', '$gang', '');";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_oa);
            header('Location: ../view/adduser.php?signup_oa=success');
            exit();


           }
        }
    }

}
```

КОД ФОРМЫ HTML

```
<section id="content2">
        <div class="wrap-main">
            <h3>Добавление сотрудника в отдел ОA</h3>
            </br>
            <form action="../Dev/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
                <label class="pure-material-textfield-outlined">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" " class="okk"><span>ФИО</span>
                </label>
                <label class="pure-material-textfield-outlined">
                    <input type="text" name="nick" placeholder=" " class="okk"><span>Ник
                    </span>
                </label>
                <label class="pure-material-textfield-outlined">
                    <select size="1" name="position">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Должность</option>
                        <option value="Оператор ООА">Оператор ООА</option>
                        <option value="Оператор ОТП">Оператор ОТП</option>
                   </select>
                </label>
                <label class="pure-material-textfield-outlined">
                    <select size="1" name="category">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Категория</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                   </select>
                </label>
                <label class="pure-material-textfield-outlined">
                    <select size="1" name="gang">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Смена</option>
                        <option value="1 Q4">1 Q4</option>
                        <option value="2 Sazeke">2 Sazeke</option>
                        <option value="3 Ночная">3 Ночная</option>
                        <option value="4 Пятидневная">4 Пятидневная</option>
                   </select>
                </label>
                    <button class="pure-material-button-contained" type="submit" name="oa-submit">Добавить</button>
            </form>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Добавьте проверку на ошибки после выполнения запросов и куда нибудь их пишите. гадать нет ли где ошибки синтаксиса из за какой нибудь лишней кавычки можно очень долго. Кроме того, обращаю ваше внимание, что создание новой таблицы в процессе работы приложения обычно очень плохая идея. Структура БД должна оставаться постоянной.

Comment: @Mike ошибки синтаксиса нет. перепроверено, переписано

Comment: Хотя я не понимаю, вот вы вставляете в таблицу сразу первую строку. А где и кто в эту таблицу будет вставлять следующие строки ? Ведь вам тогда и там надо будет имя таблицы спрашивать. И потом, что бы получить записи из таблицы, опять узнавать у пользователя из какой именно ?

Comment: @Mike Прошу прощения, выводы таблиц БД я уже сделал. Сейчас у меня возникла проблема с созданием этих самых таблиц. Именно с этим вопросом я сейчас здесь

Comment: Вот прямо перед тем как выполняется запрос распечатайте на экран переменную $sql, и попробуйте выполнить то что будет напечатано. И еще кстати совершенно не понятно, зачем вы пытаетесь создать много таблиц с одним и тем же именем в цикле. Вы ведь в цикле читаете по одной сроке вывод команды show tables и прямо в этом цикле создаете новую таблицу

Comment: И да, я надеюсь вы в курсе, что MySQL для каждой таблицы заводит по 3 файла. Если в БД окажется пара сотен таблиц ваш MySQL начнет падать с ошибкой превышения лимита открытых файлов в ОС

Comment: @В курсе. Таблиц будет всего несколько. Проблем с этим не будет.

Comment: @Mike Добавьте совет с распечаткой $sql в ответ. Мне помог, я поставлю оценку и укажу где была проблема\

Comment: Я не могу дать никакого ответа, кроме того, что уже написал Ипатьев. И если помог такой простой совет, то значит ваш вопрос следует закрыть с формулировкой "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой".

Comment: Двойной аккаунт, Дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942905/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам уже не раз говорили, что **нельзя** создавать таблицы из имен пользователей. Вы путаете таблицы и строки.

Таблица должна **одна.** При вводе данных в форму в неё добавляются **строки**.

Comment: Простите, когда мне говорили подобное? Напомните пожалуйста. И не могли бы вы более внятно разъяснить мне как правильно создать таблицу название которой берется из формы?

Comment: @ЮрийГалай А вам не надо создавать таблицу с названием, берущимся их формы. вам нужна только одна таблица, например users в которой будут имена пользователей. И должна быть таблица, одна, с той структурой, что вы сейчас создаете в скрипте и в ней поле user_id, собственно id пользователя которому принадлежит эта конкретная запись. Если вы так не сделаете, то вы просто списка записей всех clerk чисто для себя даже получить не сможете, потому что вам надо будет в запросе перечислять все таблицы которые у вас есть

Comment: @Mike Я перечислю если надо будет, но в данный момент у меня есть потребность для создания отдельной таблицы КАЖДОМУ сотруднику. Не могу поверить, что это не возможно

Comment: @ЮрийГалай То, что вы хотите - это нарушение реляционной модели данных. Вы фактически сделали велосипед с квадратными колесами, а теперь жалуетесь, что на нем неудобно ездить. Либо учитесь делать круглые колеса, либо не жалуйтесь, что плохо едет.